# C++ returning a reference to a template

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-reference

The following is a tiny part of my homework which I found to be wrong during the tests I wrote for the code.

I have a templated Array class 
In that class, I have function named get which returns a refernce to the Template, It's signature is :

```
template <class T>
T& Array<T>::get(int index)
```

Obviously, I want to be able to get a value from the array - and every change I do in the function, will change the original value in the array aswell. 
I have the following call :

```
Company Hiring=companies.get(companyID);
```

It does returns a Company with the same data, but whenever I change it (lets say, adding a worker, changing number of employees,...) and returns, the Company in the array does not change and stays blank.

What am I doing wrong ? do you have any ideas ?

If you need more details \ code please tell me and I'll edit.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe what you mean is:

```
Company& hiring = companies.get(companyID);
```

If you're not capturing a reference in that variable, you're making a copy that will never change unless you manipulate it directly.

Comment: OMG. How i missed it.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing wrong is that you are making copy of the `Company` returned by `companies.get(companyID)`. If you wanted to change the contents of companies, you would need to assign to a reference:

```
Company& Hiring = companies.get(companyID);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Hiring` is a copy of the array element. Modifying that won't change the copy in the array. Instead, you want a reference to the array element:

```
Company& Hiring=companies.get(companyID);
       ^
```